# Releasing Android App with the debug key

Tags: android

I realized that I released my android app to Google Play with a debug key and somehow the developer console couldn't detect that it was a debug key. Now I can't change my key obviously but I can update the app with the old key. keytool says the key expires in 2040 but I read that debug keys have 1 year of expiry. So should I be worried that I won't be able to update my app anymore in the future?

Comment: You cannot upload your application with a debug key. Maybe with "debug key" you mean a your "debug system key". Ignore it and continue with this key.

Comment: Also, the one-year expiration limit was lifted a while back. My debug signing key is good until 2041, at which point in time I am unlikely to be doing Android development. :-)

Comment: I'm using nVidia's Visual Studio extension for building instead of Eclipse. Maybe it's related to that?